# Remove default "Welcome to site" message in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I am using the nexus theme in drupal 7.I want to remove default "Welcome to site" message in Drupal 7 without make any page,article etc.I make the some block in the front page.
please help me..
thanks..

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in your theme's template file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
        unset($vars['page']['content']['system_main']['default_message']); //will remove message "no front page content is created"
        drupal_set_title(''); //removes welcome message (page title)
    }
}
```

Rock On :)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in template.php:

```
function nexus_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    unset($vars['page']['content']['system_main']['default_message']); //will remove message "no front page content is created"
    drupal_set_title(''); //removes welcome message (page title)
}
}
```

Additionally, I had to remove the following from line 51-53:
    if ($has_main_menu or $has_secondary_menu) {
        $vars['classes_array'][] = 'with-navigation';
    }

Answer (score 1):

In your template.php file add this code to THEME_preprocess_page function:

```
    if ($variables['is_front']) {
    $variables['title']="";
    unset($variables['page']['content']['system_main']['default_message']);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In template.php file, added this code on **function evolve_preprocess_node(&$vars)** function:

```
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
   drupal_set_title(''); //removes welcome message (page title)
```

It works for me.